# If I use my own in app billing do I still need to pay google 30% if I post my app on the market?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

If I use my own payment processing for in app billing and want to post the app on the Android market do I still need to pay Google 30% or do they not care?

Comment: Holy cow... 30%? Rip-off city. This saddens me :-/

Comment: For what's worth, see this: [In-App Purchasing For Applications?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=3c47284987b99696&hl=en) (Which doesn't seem to have a clear conclusion ;-) In any case, this belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any application distributed via Android Market needs to use Google's payment processor.

See the last sentence of paragraph 3.3:
http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: where do you get this information? what about apps like lookout that use their own billing?

Comment: and paypal in app billing as well.